# how can i put Whats App js With static html for mobile view

Tags: wordpress

I have raw HTML on which I want to js code WhatsApp will it be functional. I also need to it work properly I have create separate moblie page

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add some code to your question please?

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add js code of WhatsApp with raw HTML because you need a separate js file for it. The alternative for this is to put the WhatsApp icon and give WhatsApp link to it.

Please can you send a screenshot of your mobile view website